# Can't see database diagram in SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I wonder how to enable database diagram in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database. When I create new db I am able to open database diagram:

[image: sample]

but when I connect to existing db from Azure I can't generate database diagram:

[image: sample2]

It's connected with DB rights?

Comment: I don't think Azure supports database diagrams (among many other things). See [this blog post](http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/create-database-diagrams-of-your-windows-azure-sql-databases/), for example.

Comment: Yes that is solution.

Answer (score 0):

In database properties, do check if you are the owner - under "Files" tab. 
When restored from another server, owner may not be the same. 
Set yourself ("computer"\"user") as owner, there are your diagrams